# How can I extract a line profile from an image?

Tags: image-processing, multidimensional-array, extract, dm-script

I'm trying to extract the line profile from diffraction patterns(2D image).

The ROI is known like (x1,y1) to (x2,y2).

My challenge is to do this on an original source that is a 4D image *(scanned real space) x (diff image)*

and then convert this to a 3D *(scanned real space) x (line profile)* data.

A script that only extracts the lineprofile from diffraction would already be helpful.

I think SliceN would be the best for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The script command to extract a Lineprofile of a 2D image with perpendicular averaging is `LiveProfile_ExtractLineProfile`, and the following example would work on a 2D diffraction pattern:

```
image DPImg := GetFrontImage()
number kx1 = 77 
number ky1 = 77
number kx2 = 175
number ky2 = 175
number pWidth = 10
image profile := LiveProfile_ExtractLineProfile(DPImg,kx1,ky1,kx2,ky2,pwidth)
profile.ShowImage()
```

If you have a 4D stack, then your're right that you need to use the `SliceN` command to access the according "plane" or diffraction pattern at specified X/Y. The following script would do that:

```
image DPStack := GetFrontImage()
number sx = DPStack.ImageGetDimensionSize(0) 
number sy = DPStack.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)
number ksx = DPStack.ImageGetDimensionSize(2)
number ksy = DPStack.ImageGetDimensionSize(3)
number px = sx/2
number py = sy/2
image DPImg := DPStack.SliceN( 4,2, px,py,0,0, 2,ksx,1, 3,ksy,1 )
number kx1 = 77 
number ky1 = 77
number kx2 = 175
number ky2 = 175
number pWidth = 10
image profile := LiveProfile_ExtractLineProfile(DPImg,kx1,ky1,kx2,ky2,pwidth)
profile.ShowImage()
```

Putting all of this back into the format you need, is a matter of iteration and data insertion, which you can do with slice commands as well.

---

Note: The following [example script](https://dm-script.tugraz.at/dm/source_codes/419) from the [DM Scripting database](https://www.felmi-zfe.at/dm-script/) might be a useful reference for you as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and precise answer. Following your script, I could successfully achieved my purpose ! Thanks again. :)